# Javascript: Filter an array of objects on multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

I'm trying to filter a grid using multiple filters of various types (boolean, string match, etc.).  The grid is just a JSON array.  I have to filter every time a filter value is set or removed (i.e. a checkbox is checked, or unchecked).  I was trying to do this using a very complex switch statement, but then I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52667763/806873) by @ori-drori which explains how to do this using a much simpler map of filterHandlers.  However, when I run this code I don't get the desired results and I'm stumped as to why.  Here's what I've got:

```
filterGrid(rows) {
   const filterList = [
     { 'open': this.onlyOpen },
     { 'assmtComplete': this.onlyAssmtCompleted },
     { 'bureau': this.selectedBureau ? this.selectedBureau : '' },
     { 'unit': this.selectedUnit ? this.selectedUnit : '' }
   ];
   const filterHandlers = new Map([
     [
      'open',
      (ref) => !ref.cwsClosureReasonDescription
     ],
     [
      'assmtComplete',
      (ref) => ref.safetyAsstComplDate !== null
     ],
     [ 
      'bureau', 
      (ref, val) => ref.bureauCode === val 
     ],
     [ 
      'unit', 
      (ref, val) => ref.unitID === val 
     ],
   ]);

   const applyFilters = (arr, filters) => {
      const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);  
      return arr.filter(o => filterKeys.every((key) => {
        const handler = filterHandlers.get(key);  // THIS returns undefined every time
        return !handler || handler(o[key], filters[key]);
      }));
   };

   const result = applyFilters(rows, filterList);
   console.log(result);
 }
```

A sample object in the "rows" might look like this:

```
{
   createdDate: "2019-10-18T10:56:43.477"
   closureReasonDescription: null
   refNumber: "1231-3213-2132-1321321"
   incidentZipCode: "92108"
   intakeDate: "2019-10-19T00:56:24.953"
   referralId: 1461
   bureauCode: "S"
   unitID: 1017
   safetyAsstComplDate: null
   taskTypeId: null
}
```

As you can see from the comment in the code above, that line in the applyFilters is always undefined.  I've tried a few ways of getting the handler from that, but I'm not sure what key is supposed to be - an integer or a string?  Any tips would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: A key is the name of a property in the object, so "createdDate" in your example.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought, but the line "const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);" returns an array of strings, which are actually just the index of each filter (i.e. ["0","1","2","3"]).  It should return this though: ["open","assmtComplete","bureau","unit"], right?  So how do I get the correct keys?  Thanks

Comment: For Object.keys to work, filterList needs to be defined like this

const filterList = {
open: this.onlyOpen,
assmtComplete: this.onlyAssmtCompleted,
etc...};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filterKeys` (defined by `Object.keys(filterList)`) is an array of numeric keys (`["0", "1", "2", "3"]`) since `filterList` is an array whose keys are numeric indices.

I think you want `filterKeys` to be the keys of each object in the `filterList` array. This could be achieved most easily by making `filterList` a single object, with many keys, instead of an array of objects with one key each:

```
const filterList = {
    'open': this.onlyOpen,
    'assmtComplete': this.onlyAssmtCompleted,
    'bureau': this.selectedBureau ? this.selectedBureau : '',
    'unit': this.selectedUnit ? this.selectedUnit : ''
];
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, it should be an object with keys.  I made that change, and now it's grabbing the correct filter to compare each record against.  Thank you!